# Webpack 5 assets modules: raw-loader vs asset/source

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-5, raw-loader

I have a basic webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './example.js',
  experiments: {
    asset: true,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      { test: /\.png$/, type: 'asset/resource' },
      { test: /\.html$/, use: ['raw-loader'] },
      // { test: /\.html$/, type: 'asset/source' },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

This configuration inject the `bundle.js` in the `index.html` using the `html-webpack-plugin`. However, I needed a loader for html and I used raw loader. Everything was working fine.

Then, I wanted to use the feature asset modules. Looking at the [webpack 5 asset modules documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules), it seems that `asset/source` is the same that `raw-loader`, therefore I change the loader with this type (see the commented code in the webpack config above) and the output of the index.html is not what I had before. Indeed, it seems that it is interpreted by webpack instead of just raw like before.

> var _ =
> **non_webpack_require**("C:\Users...\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js");module.exports
> = function (templateParams) { with(templateParams) {return (function(data) { var __t, __p = ''; __p += '<!doctype
> html>Webpack App'; return __p
> })();}}

Looking at the [documentation of `html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/main/docs/template-option.md#3-setting-a-loader-using-the-modulerules-syntax), if there is a html loader, it will use it. It means that `asset/source` does not work like `raw-loader`.